# how to get stream from an Image in c

Tags: c, stream

Is there anyway in C to get an image, stream by stream and how can I understand how many stream there are in an Image?

the Image is in JPEEG type.
and for saving this stream in another file I'll have any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any external library what you have as a jpeg image is simply a binary file. You may do whatever with it via fopen(), fscanf() or any other file functions.

```
for saving this stream in another file I'll have any problem?
```

No problem if you are just coping a jpeg image to another new file. But problem may be there if you change the image extension. Please have a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

Comment: The file extension is not a problem. For example, programs universally use `.jpeg` and `.jpg` interchangeably, so changing between these extensions is never a problem. For other programs, the file extension is not used because the magic number is used to identify the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to the free OpenCV library : http://opencv.org/

Here there is a tutorial with some examples : http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

It's largely used for this kind of treatments.

Comment: Its so complex for just one task